# WPF Fast Click Events become a Drag-Event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have the problem, that fast clicks become a drag-event.

I use the preventMouseButtonDown event to get the start position:

```
private void previewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    _pointStartDrag = e.GetPosition(null);
}
```

The previewMouseMove-event delivers the actual position. I compare the two points to trigger my drag-event.

```
Vector d = _pointStartDrag - e.GetPosition(null);
if( |d.x| > minDx || |d.y| > minDy)
    //here is my drag-event
```

Whatever minDx/y is set, it is reached by fast clicking two different poinst on my gui.

I don't know what went wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Why aren't use using the [built-in WPF support for Drag&Drop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just answered this problem a day or two ago, but I can't find the question now, so I'll just do it again. You can use the `SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance` and `SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance` properties for this purpose:

```
private bool IsConfirmedDrag(Point point)
{
    bool horizontalMovement = Math.Abs(point.X - dragStartPosition.X) > 
        SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance;
    bool verticalMovement = Math.Abs(point.Y - dragStartPosition.Y) > 
        SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance;
    return (horizontalMovement | verticalMovement);
}
```

It is used like this:

```
private void DragSourcePreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isMouseDown && IsConfirmedDrag(e.GetPosition(sender as ListBox)))
    {
        isMouseDown = false;
        ...
        // Start Drag operation
    }
}
```

Comment: tyvm, I'll try it out.